# TextBlock1 is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

As silly as this sounds I'm a little stumped at this one. Here's my XAML in a Win Phone 8 App:

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Page" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I've searched around but I don't know why I can't write code against the TextBlock1 control in code behind. When I type TextBlock1.Text= .... I get the error *TextBlock1 is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.*  But I can't see how it is private?

All I'm trying to do is add a textblock, assign some content to it, and then that selected value is passed across another page to perform relevant action.

In addition as soon as I remove it outside of the PhoneListSelector I can access it.

Comment: The `TextBlock` is a template for items in a list, how would you know which `TextBlock` you were setting the text of?

Comment: you have set itemtemplate for your itemsControl... there will as many textboxes as the number of items... which one do you want?... you cant access it as it is not defined in main window...it will be accessible only in ListItem

Comment: Also why is this tagged C# and VB.NET?

Comment: I am using TextBlock1.Inlines.Add to create a list and then action the selected item, so i would have tackled the selected item if i could get past the reason why its private. I tagged it C# and VB .Net as there was code which was in VB .Net/C# and some devs do both XAML /C#/VB .Net
@Nit - how would i define it in the main window?

Comment: @Computer I think you are missing an important point though, if you did `TextBlock.Inlines.Add` you would be continually adding to the first item in the list, rather than actually adding to the list as I assume you intend (otherwise just get rid of the list and problem solved).  Unfortunately there is no easy way to do this in WPF if you insist on taking the winforms approach and accessing the UI by name, but is quite easy if you don't mind re-tooling some logic so your list is bound to a list of strings that each item's textbox is bound to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TextBlock1** is **defined inside an ItemTemplate**, anything defined a Template cannot be access directly as it will be created on runtime by the control.

You probably need to do binding on the TextBlock if you want to manipulate anything that the LongListSelector's DataContext has.

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" Text="{Binding Content"} HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

```cs
MainLongListSelector.DataContext = new List<TestViewModel>();

public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 //Assuming you've implemented the interface
  private string _content;
  public string Content { get { return _content; } { set { _content = value; NotifyOfPropertyChanged("Content"); } }
}
```

From here, you can try to access the selected value content and pass that to the next page.

```cs
var selectedItem = MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem as TestViewModel;
GoToNextPage(selectedItem.Content);
```

I strongly suggest to read MVVM design pattern and everything should be easy for you to implement, always remember **UI is not DATA** it's responsibility is only to show something that is passed through the ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant explanation. Just to make sure i dont confuse myself any further i just wanted to confirm that i have a 3 screen process. Screen 1 lists some options for the user (i.e Type of holiday), screen 2 displays the top level (Country to visit) screen 3 shows the final output (hotel to stay at). The information is retrieved from a web service. When i tried using a similar approach as you have suggested i ran into problems. Are there any links i could follow to do this correctly? Or an example of how it all fits together? Thanks

Comment: There is, that is if you are familiar on how to use the MVVM pattern.